# Selected Value for CategoryFilter won't change

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

So my issue is that I am trying to change the title of a bar chart based on which state is selected in statePicker. However, since I want to have Alabama preselected for the user, every time I select a new state in statePicker, it updates the chart with the correct data but when the listener is called to update the title, the title always shows Alabama.

```
// Define a category picker control for the State 
statePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'dropdown_control_div',
    'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'State',
        'ui': {
            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
            'allowTyping': false,
            'allowMultiple': false,
            'allowNone': false,
            'caption' : 'Select a state',
            'cssClass': "style.css"
        }
    },
   'state': { 'selectedValue': ['Alabama'] }
});  



google.visualization.events.addListener(statePicker, 'statechange', function () {

    var state = statePicker.getState();
    programmaticChart.title = "Murder Rate in " + state.selectedValue;
});
```

Any tips on how to get the title to update properly would be helpful. Thank you!